# Perl hostname regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have the following snippet code:

```
my $hostname =  `host \`hostname\``;
```

which this yields something like :

`blahblah.test1234.mydomain.com has address 12.345.67.8910`  (I replaced the real values with dummy values)

from here, I want to extract this so that `$hostname` only has "`blahblah.test1234.mydomain.com`" and forget the rest

Such piece of code will be ran in different servers so the size of this can vary.

I was thinking using a regular expression that will be cut from the beginning of the line up to `mydomain.com`   so basically `*.mydomain.com`

Comment: Could you please indent your code by 4 spaces? The backticks are causing absolute mayhem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using perl's own `gethostbyname` or `Net::DNS::Resolver` instead of shelling out to a command line program.

Comment: thanks I ended up using use Net::Domain qw (hostname hostfqdn hostdomain); and my $hostname = hostfqdn();

Comment: `gethostbyname` is the old IPv4-specific legacy deprecated resolver.
For modern stuff, you want to be using `Socket::getaddrinfo()`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the core module [Sys::Hostname](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/ext/Sys-Hostname/Hostname.pm):

```
perl -MSys::Hostname -le 'print hostname'
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the related question in your code (namely; "How do I determine the canonical name of a given DNS query name"), see the `AI_CANONNAME` flag to `Socket::getaddrinfo()`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket qw( getaddrinfo AI_CANONNAME );

my ( $err, @res ) = getaddrinfo( $ARGV[0], "", { flags => AI_CANONNAME } );
die "$err\n" if $err;

print "$res[0]->{canonname}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you only want to keep whatever's before the first whitespace, try this:

```
$hostname =~ s/(.*?)\s+.*/\1/;
```

It will produce 'blahblah.test1234.mydomain.com' for the following:

```
$hostname = "blahblah.test1234.mydomain.com has address 12.345.67.8910";
$hostname =~ s/(.*?)\s+.*/\1/;
print($hostname);
```